# разделить один аргумент ф-ци на два

Tags: javascript, замыкания

знакомый задал задачу, как сделать следующее:

```
sum (q, e) = sum (q)(e);
```

**UPDATE** функция должна принимать не ограниченное количество аргументов

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Answer (score 4):

Для принятия списка параметров, достаточно добавить возможность их обрабатывать, например с помощью функции [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
function sum() {
  function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  };

  var num = [].reduce.call(arguments, add);

  function inner() {
    return sum.apply(this, [].concat.apply([num], arguments));
  }
  inner.toString = inner.valueOf = inner.toJSON = function() {
    return num;
  }
  return inner;
}

function o(prepend, val){
  document.getElementById('res').innerHTML += (prepend? (prepend+": "):"")+(typeof val == 'string'? val : JSON.stringify(val)) + '<br />';
}

o('sum(1,2,3)(4,5,6)(7)',sum(1,2,3)(4,5,6)(7));
o('sum(1,2,3)',sum(1,2,3));
o('sum(1)(2,3)', sum(1)(2,3));
o('sum(1,2)(3)',sum(1,2)(3));
o('sum(1,2)(3)+"4"',sum(1,2)(3)+"4");
o('sum(1)(2,3)+4',sum(1)(2,3)+4); //10
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: Вот это хардкор :D

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, а на en.SO такой вариант у меня минусанули :)

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос не вполне понятен, но, возможно, имеется в виду нечто вроде такого?

```
var sum = function(q) {
   return function(e) { 
      return q + e;
   }
}
```

Comment: ну конечно, такой вариант тоже может быть, я но извините, зыбыл уточнить что функция должна принимать не ограниченное количество аргументов, например как описано тут 
https://habrahabr.ru/post/226325/

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов, тогда чем не устраивает вариант по ссылке?